# I want use schema in fastify routes but its returning empty object but if i comment schema code it is working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

**I want use schema in fastify routes but its returning empty object but if i comment schema code it is working correctly**
**router array containing routes and i have looped on it**

```
const routes = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        handler: getAllTodos,
        schema: {
            response: {
                200: {
                    type: 'object',
                    properties: {
                        _id: { type: 'string' },
                        task: { type: 'string' },
                        createdAt: { type: 'string' },
                        updatedAt: { type: 'string' },
                        __v: { type: 'number' }
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        url: '/app/todos/'
    }
]


routes?.map((route, index) => (
    fastify.route(route)
))
```

Comment: what do you mean with "returning empty object"?

Comment: Maybe what you're getting back is an array of objects, so your 'type' should be 'array'?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon { }

Comment: I mean: who is returning the {}? The route when you call it? If so, could you share the `getAllTodos` function? the name suggests me that it returns an array

Comment: exports.getAllTodos = (req, res) => {
    Todo.find((err, todos) => {
        if (err || !todos) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Something went wrong in finding all todos",
            });
        }
        // res.json(todos);
        res.send(todos)
    });
};
@ManuelSpigolon
I have updated the type to array now it  returning whole data but I only want data that I mention in properties

Comment: Pleas update your answer, I think there are some issues in the json schema. Moreover the res.json method doesn't exist in fastify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are responding with an array then the properties, i.e. the keys of any array, are 0, 1, 2 etc. So your schema asking for _id, task etc will have no effect. Instead use 'items' to look inside each array item.

```
response: {
  200: {
    type: 'array',
    items: { 
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        _id: { type: 'string' },
        task: { type: 'string' },
        // etc.
      }
    }
  }
}
```